# Handling same name symbols in C

Tags: c, software-design

Suppose that I have an app written in C that must parse some blob data. The parsing process is done by an entire dedicated library (I have access to this library code).
Since this blob is versioned I need to support let's say 2 versions of it at a time. Workflow would be something like:

1. 'v1' is out -> library supports 'v1'
2. 'v2' is out -> library now supports 'v2' and 'v1'
3. 'v3' is out -> library now supports 'v3' and 'v2'

and so on.

The main problem is that the majority of symbols in the library for 'v2', for example, are also present in 'v1' library, with the same function prototype.

First thought was use something like namespaces in C++, in order to have something like:

```
/app/src/lib_v1/parser.c

void _parse_blob(char* blob){ //data parsing code for v1}
/////////////////////////////


/app/src/lib_v2/parser.c

void _parse_blob(char* blob){ //data parsing code for v2}
////////////////////////////


/app/src/main.c

//Pseudo-code
char* data;
if(_check_version(data) == 'v1')
   parser.v1._parse_blob(data);
else
   parser.v2._parse_blob(data);
```

But I don't know if any similar can be achieved in C **without changing anything in the code of the 'outgoing' library** (v1 in this case) since all that code has already been tested and modifying it would invalidate all the release tests.

Other idea would be separate both libraries code into two dynamic linked libraries and load/unload them when necessary, but don't know if could work or if it is efficient.

What would be the best approach to this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you just prefix the functions by version and have some kind of dispatcher function that calls the correct one to initiate the parsing process? This is tagged C, but in C++ you could have a base Parser class and specialize that for various versions, then use a factory method to instantiate a parser for a particular version.

Comment: Maybe that could work but I want to keep the 'old' code untouched if possible, I mean, by doing what you say I should rename (add prefix) all functions, right?

Comment: Prefixes make it abundantly clear which version any particular function belongs to, so it'd be the most obvious way of providing separation. You could also try some wizardry with macros, but that's how code-bases usually end up too confusing to work with by anyone other than the original author.

Comment: Keep `parse_blob` for v1, add `parse_blob_v2` for v2, simple enough, no need to touch existing code. Bonus: add `parse_blob_v1` as an alias for `parse_blob` and deprecate `parse_blob`.

Comment: There is of course the question of if parsing these different versions could all be done in the same parser, where you're just adding branches to an existing parse tool. Some parser generators make this super easy to do, and maintaining separation is actually far more of a hassle since you have three different parsers to write instead of one.

Comment: Also it's often the case that the *output* of the parser remains fixed even if the input takes various forms. That is the V2 parser produces V2 output, and the V1 (V2) parser produces V2 output. Then V3 -> V3, V1 (V3) -> V3, V2 (V3) -> v3 and so on. This often makes a stronger case for a singular parser that can just *deal*.